# Regular Expressions expected string or bytes like object

Tags: python, python-re

Hello I am trying to take emails from a txt file but I cant I dont know why the error is

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

```
import re

pattern_email = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.com|edu|net")

with open("Yeni Metin Belgesi (4).txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
     content=f.read
     matches = pattern_email.finditer(content)
     for match in matches:
        print(match)
```

[image: this is the text file]

Comment: Your regex pattern is off and should use an alternation at the end for the various extensions: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(?:com|edu|net)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f.read` is a method, so you need to do `f.read()`

do note that `.read()` will read the entire file, you may want to iterate it line by line instead

Comment: hahahaha  I cant believe thats the problem I`ve been looking for 40 mins Thank you